# Molar Conductivities of H+ and OH- V/S other Ionic Electrolytes

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, conductivity

The following table gives the Ionic Molar Conductivities of a few electrolytes in water. What are the reasons for the unusually high values for both H$^+$ and OH$^-$ even though both undergo solvation in water? Why do they retain their mobility in water even after solvation?

\begin{array}{lr}
\text{Electrolyte} & \text{Ionic Molar Conductivity (mS m$^2$ mol$^{-1})$} \\
\hline
\text{H$^+$} & 34.96 \\
\text{Li$^+$} & 3.87\\
\text{Mg$^{+2}$} & 10.60 \\
\text{[N(CH$_3$)$_4$]$^+$} & 4.49 \\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{lr}
\text{Electrolyte}&\text{ Ionic Molar Conductivity (mS m$^2$ mol$^{-1})$} \\
\hline
\text{OH$^-$} & 19.91\\
\text{F$^-$} & 5.54\\
\text{CO$_3$$^{2-}$} & 13.86\\
\text{HCO$_2$$^-$} & 5.46\\
\end{array}

Comment: Your question looks better then old one, but there are answers already.